# Change \graphicspath based on current user of document

Tags: graphics

I am working with someone else on a shared .tex document.

We have a shared dropbox file /images that holds all the images in our document

However, on each of our machines the path to the dropbox file /images is different.

This means whenever one of us compiles we need to change the \graphicspath{...} to the path for /images that is local to our machine.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just add both?

Comment: personally I'd not use graphicspath and just each of you have dropbox in your TEXINPUTS but if you do use it note you can use relative directories and can use `~` for your home so `{\string~/dropbox/}` for example